# What is the "Value" in Scala Enum class?

Tags: scala, class

I am new to scala and I am reading the Enum class in this page(https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Enumeration.html)
I have two questions:

1. In the definition of WeekDay, what is the "Value" in val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = "Value"
2. After the definition of object WeekDay, why we need "import WeekDay._" here ?

Thank you!

[Screenshot of the code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN4Tl.png)

Comment: The Enum class in Scala 2 is pretty gross. No one really uses it, people tend to hand-roll sealed traits, use third-party libraries like enumeratum or even Java enums instead. So don't spend too much energy on this. Good news: Scala 3 has revamped, much better enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From scala doc

> Each call to a Value method adds a new unique value to the enumeration. To be accessible, these values are usually defined as val members of the enumeration.

So `Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun` are just simply values, each instantiated by calling a function called `Value` (see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L162)

2. Importing is not for defining the Weekdays but for the usage. Notice that Mon, Tue, etc is defined inside the object. Just like every identifiers in scala, you need to import to access identifiers defined in another package or object. It'll be clearer if you define the enum in 1 file and use it another file
3. You didn't ask but in many cases you should also consider using `sealed trait` or plain java enum so that you get exhaustive matching warning. It's a very useful thing that scala compiler tells you when you don't handle all the cases in enumeration. Many people consider that an error in modeling if you can't handle all the cases. See https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html

Comment: Importantly, `Value` is *not* a Scala keyword. It's an ordinary method on `Enumeration` that does exactly what we need it to do. If it were not provided by the standard library, we could write it ourselves.

Comment: Also, while rarely used, you can do something like `val a, b = new StringBuilder()` in Scala and both `a` and `b` will be _different_ `StringBuilder`s. That's the feature used for `val X, Y, Z = Value`